# GCC - expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof' - IT++ 4.2 in Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I have built CLAPACK in my Android NDK project successfully. Next, I tried to put IT++ 4.2 library inside. However, I have some errors that i could not fix. These are the something that i did in my project:

First, I copy itpp folder to jni folder of my project and modified config.h in itpp.

Because I found isfinite, isinf and isnan function in  (place in ..android-ndk-r7b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include). I set HAVE_DECL_ISINF, HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE and HAVE_DECL_ISNAN to 1.

**config.h**

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H


/* Define to dummy `main' function (if any) required to link to the Fortran
   libraries. */
/* #undef F77_DUMMY_MAIN */

/* Define if F77 and FC dummy `main' functions are identical. */
/* #undef FC_DUMMY_MAIN_EQ_F77 */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `acosh' function. */
#define HAVE_ACOSH 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `asinh' function. */
#define HAVE_ASINH 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `atanh' function. */
#define HAVE_ATANH 1

/*#if defined(HAVE_ACML) || defined(HAVE_MKL)
/* Define if you have a BLAS library. */
#define HAVE_BLAS 1
/*#endif

#ifdef HAVE_ACML
/* Define if you have an ACML BLAS library. */
/*#  define HAVE_BLAS_ACML 1
/*#endif

/* Define if you have an ATLAS BLAS library. */
/* #undef HAVE_BLAS_ATLAS */

/*#ifdef HAVE_MKL
/* Define if you have an MKL BLAS library. */
/*#  define HAVE_BLAS_MKL 1
/*#endif

/* Define to 1 if you have the `cbrt' function. */
#  define HAVE_CBRT 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <cmath> header file. */
/*#define HAVE_CMATH 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <complex> header file. */
/*#define HAVE_COMPLEX 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the declaration of `isfinite', and to 0 if you
   don't. */
#define HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the declaration of `isinf', and to 0 if you don't.
   */
#define HAVE_DECL_ISINF 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the declaration of `isnan', and to 0 if you don't.
   */
#define HAVE_DECL_ISNAN 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the declaration of `signgam', and to 0 if you
   don't. */
/*#define HAVE_DECL_SIGNGAM 0

/* Define to 1 if you have the <dlfcn.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `erf' function. */
#define HAVE_ERF 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `erfc' function. */
#define HAVE_ERFC 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `expm1' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_EXPM1 */

/* Define if the compiler supports extern template */
/* #undef HAVE_EXTERN_TEMPLATE */

#if defined(HAVE_ACML) || defined(HAVE_MKL)
/* Define if you have FFT library. */
#  define HAVE_FFT 1
#endif

/* Define if you have FFTW3 library. */
/* #undef HAVE_FFTW3 */

#ifdef HAVE_ACML
/* Define if you have ACML FFT library. */
#  define HAVE_FFT_ACML 1
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_MKL
/* Define if you have MKL FFT library. */
#  define HAVE_FFT_MKL 1
#endif

/* Define to 1 if you have the `finite' function. */
#define HAVE_FINITE 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `fpclass' function. */
/*#define HAVE_FPCLASS 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <ieeefp.h> header file. */
/* #undef HAVE_IEEEFP_H */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <inttypes.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `isfinite' function. */
#define HAVE_ISFINITE 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `isinf' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_ISINF */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `isnan' function. */
/*#define HAVE_ISNAN 1

/*#if defined(HAVE_ACML) || defined(HAVE_MKL)
/* Define if you have LAPACK library. */
#define HAVE_LAPACK 1
/*#endif

/* Define to 1 if you have the `lgamma' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_LGAMMA */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `log1p' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_LOG1P */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `log2' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_LOG2 */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <memory.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `rint' function. */
#define HAVE_RINT 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdint.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdlib.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `std::isfinite' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_STD_ISFINITE */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `std::isinf' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_STD_ISINF */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `std::isnan' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_STD_ISNAN */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <strings.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <string.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/stat.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/types.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `tgamma' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_TGAMMA */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <unistd.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1

/* Define if you use zdotusub_ Fortran wrapper. */
/* #undef HAVE_ZDOTUSUB */

/* Define if "void zdotu_()" should be used. */
#define HAVE_ZDOTU_VOID 1

/* Define if you want exceptions handling */
/* #undef ITPP_EXCEPTIONS */

/* Name of package */
#define PACKAGE "itpp"

/* Define to the address where bug reports for this package should be sent. */
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ediap@users.sourceforge.net"

/* Define to the full name of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "IT++"

/* Define to the full name and version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_STRING "IT++ 4.0.0"

/* Define to the one symbol short name of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "itpp"

/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.0.0"

/* The size of `int', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_INT 4

/* The size of `long', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_LONG 4

/* The size of `long long', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_LONG_LONG 8

/* The size of `short', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_SHORT 2

/* The size of `unsigned int', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_INT 4

/* The size of `unsigned long', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG 4

/* The size of `unsigned long long', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG 8

/* The size of `unsigned short', as computed by sizeof. */
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_SHORT 2

/* Define to 1 if you have the ANSI C header files. */
#define STDC_HEADERS 1

/* Define to 1 if you can safely include both <sys/time.h> and <time.h>. */
/* #undef TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME */

/* Version number of package */
#define VERSION "4.0.0"


#if defined(HAVE_CMATH)
#  include <cmath>
#endif
/*#include <math.h>*/
#endif /* #ifndef CONFIG_H */
```

**math.h**

```
   [..]
    #define fpclassify(x) \
    ((sizeof (x) == sizeof (float)) ? __fpclassifyf(x) \
    : (sizeof (x) == sizeof (double)) ? __fpclassifyd(x) \
    : __fpclassifyl(x))

#define isfinite(x)                 \
    ((sizeof (x) == sizeof (float)) ? __isfinitef(x)    \
    : (sizeof (x) == sizeof (double)) ? __isfinite(x)   \
    : __isfinitel(x))
#define isinf(x)                    \
    ((sizeof (x) == sizeof (float)) ? __isinff(x)   \
    : (sizeof (x) == sizeof (double)) ? __isinf(x)  \
    : __isinfl(x))
#define isnan(x)                    \
    ((sizeof (x) == sizeof (float)) ? isnanf(x)     \
    : (sizeof (x) == sizeof (double)) ? isnan(x)    \
    : __isnanl(x))
#define isnormal(x)                 \
    ((sizeof (x) == sizeof (float)) ? __isnormalf(x)    \
    : (sizeof (x) == sizeof (double)) ? __isnormal(x)   \
    : __isnormall(x))
[..]
```

However, when i compile itpp, i received error in **itcompat.h** file

```
#ifndef ITCOMPAT_H
#define ITCOMPAT_H

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#  include <itpp/config.h>
#else
#  include <itpp/config_msvc.h>
#endif

//! \cond

// Microsoft Visual C++ underscore prefixed functions
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  include <cfloat>
#  define finite(x) _finite(x)
#  define isfinite(x) _finite(x)
#  define isnan(x) _isnan(x)
#  define fpclass(x) _fpclass(x)
#  define FP_NINF _FPCLASS_NINF
#  define FP_PINF _FPCLASS_PINF
#  define jn(a, b) _jn(a, b)
#  define yn(a, b) _yn(a, b)
#  define j0(a) _j0(a)
#  define j1(a) _j1(a)
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER)


// Solaris uses <ieeefp.h> for declaring isnan() and finite() functions
#if defined(HAVE_IEEEFP_H)
#  include <ieeefp.h>
#endif

// These definitions would collide with IT++ functions
#if defined(min)
#  undef min
#endif
#if defined(max)
#  undef max
#endif
#if defined(log2)
#  undef log2
#endif
namespace std
{

#ifndef HAVE_STD_ISINF
#if (HAVE_DECL_ISINF == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISINF)
inline int isinf(double x) { return ::isinf(x); } //line 77
#elif defined(FPCLASS)
inline int isinf(double x)
{
  if (::fpclass(a) == FP_NINF) return -1;
  else if (::fpclass(a) == FP_PINF) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
#else
inline int isinf(double x)
{
  if ((x == x) && ((x - x) != 0.0)) return (x < 0.0 ? -1 : 1);
  else return 0;
}
#endif // #if (HAVE_DECL_ISINF == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISINF)
#endif // #ifndef HAVE_STD_ISINF

#ifndef HAVE_STD_ISNAN
#if (HAVE_DECL_ISNAN == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISNAN)
inline int isnan(double x) { return ::isnan(x); }   //line 96
#else
inline int isnan(double x) { return ((x != x) ? 1 : 0); }
#endif // #if (HAVE_DECL_ISNAN == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISNAN)
#endif // #ifndef HAVE_STD_ISNAN

#ifndef HAVE_STD_ISFINITE
#if (HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISFINITE)
inline int isfinite(double x) { return ::isfinite(x); }   //line 104
#elif defined(HAVE_FINITE)
inline int isfinite(double x) { return ::finite(x); }
#else
inline int isfinite(double x)
{
  return ((!std::isnan(x) && !std::isinf(x)) ? 1 : 0);
}
#endif // #if (HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE == 1) || defined(HAVE_ISFINITE)
#endif // #ifndef HAVE_STD_ISFINITE

} // namespace std

[..]
```

**converter.cpp**

```
#include <itpp/base/converters.h>
#include <itpp/base/itcompat.h>
#include <itpp/base/matfunc.h>
#include <itpp/base/math/log_exp.h>

//! \cond

namespace itpp
{

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vector converters
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ivec to_ivec(int s) { ivec out(1); out(0) = s; return out; }

vec to_vec(double s) { vec out(1); out(0) = s; return out; }

cvec to_cvec(double real, double imag)
{
  cvec out(1);
  out(0) = std::complex<double>(real, imag);
  return out;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Miscellaneous converters
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

bvec dec2bin(int length, int index)
{
  int i, bintemp = index;
  bvec temp(length);

  for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    temp(i) = bin(bintemp & 1);
    bintemp = (bintemp >> 1);
  }
  return temp;
}

bvec dec2bin(int index, bool msb_first)
{
  int length = int2bits(index);
  int i, bintemp = index;
  bvec temp(length);

  for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    temp(i) = bin(bintemp & 1);
    bintemp = (bintemp >> 1);
  }
  if (msb_first) {
    return temp;
  }
  else {
    return reverse(temp);
  }
}

void dec2bin(int index, bvec &v)
{
  int i, bintemp = index;
  v.set_size(int2bits(index), false);

  for (i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    v(i) = bin(bintemp & 1);
    bintemp = (bintemp >> 1);
  }
}

int bin2dec(const bvec &inbvec, bool msb_first)
{
  int i, temp = 0;
  int sizebvec = inbvec.length();
  if (msb_first) {
    for (i = 0; i < sizebvec; i++) {
      temp += pow2i(sizebvec - i - 1) * int(inbvec(i));
    }
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < sizebvec; i++) {
      temp += pow2i(i) * int(inbvec(i));
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

bvec oct2bin(const ivec &octalindex, short keepzeros)
{
  int length = octalindex.length(), i;
  bvec out(3*length);
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    out.replace_mid(3*i, dec2bin(3, octalindex(i)));
  }
  //remove zeros if keepzeros = 0
  if (keepzeros == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < out.length(); i++) {
      if ((short)out(i) != 0) {
        return out.right(out.length() - i);
        break;
      }
    }
    return bvec("0");
  }
  else {
    return out;
  }
}

ivec bin2oct(const bvec &inbits)
{
  int start, Itterations = ceil_i(inbits.length() / 3.0);
  ivec out(Itterations);
  for (int i = Itterations - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    start = 3 * i - (3 * Itterations - inbits.length());
    out(i) = bin2dec(inbits.mid(start, 3));
  }
  out(0) = bin2dec(inbits.left(inbits.length() - ((Itterations - 1) * 3)));
  return out;
}

ivec bin2pol(const bvec &inbvec)
{
  return 1 -2*to_ivec(inbvec);
}

bvec pol2bin(const ivec &inpol)
{
  return to_bvec((1 -inpol) / 2);
}


// Round to nearest integer, return result in double
double round(double x) { return ::rint(x); }
// Round to nearest integer
vec round(const vec &x) { return apply_function<double>(::rint, x); }
// Round to nearest integer
mat round(const mat &x) { return apply_function<double>(::rint, x); }
// Round to nearest integer
int round_i(double x) { return static_cast<int>(::rint(x)); }

// Round to nearest integer and return ivec
ivec round_i(const vec &x) { return to_ivec(round(x)); }
// Round to nearest integer and return imat
imat round_i(const mat &x) { return to_imat(round(x)); }

// Round to nearest upper integer
ivec ceil_i(const vec &x) { return to_ivec(ceil(x)); }
// Round to nearest upper integer
imat ceil_i(const mat &x) { return to_imat(ceil(x)); }

// Round to nearest lower integer
ivec floor_i(const vec &x) { return to_ivec(floor(x)); }
// Round to nearest lower integer
imat floor_i(const mat &x) { return to_imat(floor(x)); }


cvec round_to_zero(const cvec &x, double threshold)
{
  cvec temp(x.length());

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    temp(i) = round_to_zero(x(i), threshold);

  return temp;
}

cmat round_to_zero(const cmat &x, double threshold)
{
  cmat temp(x.rows(), x.cols());

  for (int i = 0; i < x.rows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x.cols(); j++) {
      temp(i, j) = round_to_zero(x(i, j), threshold);
    }
  }

  return temp;
}

cvec round_to_infty(const cvec &in, const double threshold)
{
  cvec temp(in.length());

  for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    temp(i) = round_to_infty(in(i), threshold);

  return temp;
}

cmat round_to_infty(const cmat &in, const double threshold)
{
  cmat temp(in.rows(), in.cols());

  for (int i = 0; i < in.rows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < in.cols(); j++) {
      temp(i, j) = round_to_infty(in(i, j), threshold);
    }
  }

  return temp;
}

std::string to_str(const double &i, const int precision)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss.precision(precision);
  ss.setf(std::ostringstream::scientific, std::ostringstream::floatfield);
  ss << i;
  return ss.str();
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Instantiations
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

template bvec to_bvec(const svec &v);
template bvec to_bvec(const ivec &v);

template svec to_svec(const bvec &v);
template svec to_svec(const ivec &v);
template svec to_svec(const vec &v);

template ivec to_ivec(const bvec &v);
template ivec to_ivec(const svec &v);
template ivec to_ivec(const vec &v);

template vec to_vec(const bvec &v);
template vec to_vec(const svec &v);
template vec to_vec(const ivec &v);

template cvec to_cvec(const bvec &v);
template cvec to_cvec(const svec &v);
template cvec to_cvec(const ivec &v);
template cvec to_cvec(const vec &v);

template cvec to_cvec(const bvec &real, const bvec &imag);
template cvec to_cvec(const svec &real, const svec &imag);
template cvec to_cvec(const ivec &real, const ivec &imag);
template cvec to_cvec(const vec &real, const vec &imag);

template bmat to_bmat(const smat &m);
template bmat to_bmat(const imat &m);

template smat to_smat(const bmat &m);
template smat to_smat(const imat &m);
template smat to_smat(const mat &m);

template imat to_imat(const bmat &m);
template imat to_imat(const smat &m);
template imat to_imat(const mat &m);

template mat to_mat(const bmat &m);
template mat to_mat(const smat &m);
template mat to_mat(const imat &m);

template cmat to_cmat(const bmat &m);
template cmat to_cmat(const smat &m);
template cmat to_cmat(const imat &m);
template cmat to_cmat(const mat &m);

template cmat to_cmat(const bmat &real, const bmat &imag);
template cmat to_cmat(const smat &real, const smat &imag);
template cmat to_cmat(const imat &real, const imat &imag);
template cmat to_cmat(const mat &real, const mat &imag);

} // namespace itpp

//! \endcond
```

**Console output:**

```
Compile++ arm    : itpp <= converters.cpp

In file included from E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/converters.cpp:30:0:
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:77:12: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:77:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:77:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:96:12: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:96:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:96:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:104:12: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:104:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
E:/hello-jni/jni/itpp/base/itcompat.h:104:12: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/cygdrive/e/Soft/android-ndk-r7b/build/core/build-binary.mk:249: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/itpp/itpp/base/converters.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/itpp/itpp/base/converters.o] Error 1
```

Could you give me some advices for my problem? I'm a newbie about android-ndk.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you say which lines are giving the error? `line 77` is not so descriptive, specially since part of the file is omitted. Update: Wait a minute, you haven't even included `converters.cpp`!

Comment: @Shahbaz the line information is included in the code snippet

Comment: Ah I see it now. Kind of hidden

Comment: Try throwing a space between the `::` and the `isinf`/`isnan` on lines 77 and 96.

Comment: This is odd. Both `itcompat.h` and `math.h` are standard headers of your compiler, right? It seems like you have included `math.h` before `itcompat.h`, which means the macro `isinf` is being expanded where the function `isinf` is being declared, causing this mess.

Comment: @Shahbaz math.h is header file of android-ndk, itcompat.h is header file of it++ library. Because inside math.h we have isinf function aldready, i set HAVE_DECL_ISINF to 1 in config.h file (this file belong to it++ library).
What's should i do? Do I have to omit that line _italic_(inline int isinf) in itcompat.h?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have `isinf` defined as a macro. Later, you are trying to define a function with that name.

You should note that macros expand while the lexer is working (or even as a pass before that). This means that it expands macros without understanding parsing correctness, let alone context. That is why even though you are declaring a function in a namespace, the lexer doesn't understand it and takes the function name as a macro anyway.

To work around this, you need to make sure itcompat.h doesn't define `isinf`. From the looks of the header file, it seems like `HAVE_STD_ISINF` needs to be defined. Having `HAVE_DECL_ISINF` is not enough as in that case `isinf` is still being declared in itcompat.h. My guess is that if you include `math.h` before itcompat.h, it is going to define `HAVE_STD_ISINF` itself.

Comment: You could also define `HAVE_STD_ISINF` yourself before including itcompat.h but that is generally not a good idea.